# New Ubuntu-64-bit: Why is libgfortran.so.3 not in folder /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7?

Tags: linux-kernel, gfortran

I just installed Ubuntu-64 (ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso), and am running it in VirtualBox with VB Guest Addition in Windows 10 Pro-64.

There is an executable I am working with that needs libgfortran.so.3.  At run-time however, an exception was thrown: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So why is this fortran not installed in the /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7 folder.  Is Ubuntu Linux dumbing-down somehow, or is there a license issue?

What Linux commands can I use to fetch and install this fortran package?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer is NO, Ubuntu does not distribute fortran.  So i ran the following commands, and installed it:

```
sudo bash 
apt-get -y install gfortran
```

Comment: It clearly does distribute it when you can easily `apt-get` it.